# Caliburn.Micro - Removing an item from listbox while using dependancy injection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to remove an item from a ListBox that i fill through an AddButton, each item contains its delete button, i tried solutions outside Caliburn.micro but none seems to work for me,
i'll share with you what i tried in my last attempt:

Here's my ViewModel Code:

```
public POSViewModel()
        {

            DeleteTicket= new RelayCommand
                    (() => DeleteTicketCommand(),
                     () => CanDeleteTicket);
        }

  public RelayCommand DeleteTicket { get; private set; }

 public void DeleteTicketCommand()
        {
            Tickets.Remove(SelectedTicket);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Tickets);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Total);
        }

        public bool CanDeleteTicket {
            get
            {
                bool output = false;
                if (SelectedTicket != null)
                {
                    output = true;
                }
                return output;
            }
        }



        private TicketModel _selectedTicket;

        public TicketModel SelectedTicket
        {
            get { return _selectedTicket; }
            set {
                _selectedTicket = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedTicket);

            }
        }
```

And this is my Xaml code:

```
<ListBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  x:Name="Tickets" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTicket}">

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate >
             <StackPanel>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" CanVerticallyScroll="False">
                    <Button  Margin="5" 
                      x:Name="DeleteTicket" />
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource }" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I forgot to mention that i tried to use a button outside the listbox and it worked fine, however this is not what i want to do, i'm open to any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: You need to remember that `DataTemplate` is not part of the Visual Tree so the binding is not going to work for the ViewModel, But it will have datacontext of the item in the itemssource of the listbox. I got it to work by using x:Name on the list box and referencing that name in the binding for the command.

Comment: thank you for mentioning that didn't know that dataTemplate prevent access to the elements inside .. also, sorry for late respond i almost forgot about this.